# Flutter : Tap inside Texfield close Custom App Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing a peculiar issue with my Flutter application:

When I'm on my home page and I expand my custom AppBar, whether I tap on a TextField or not, and then close it - if I navigate to a different screen and come back, expanding the AppBar again, this time when I tap on the TextField, it causes the AppBar to close automatically. I'm puzzled as to why this is happening.

Here's the code for my custom AppBar:

```
class CustomAppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final VoidCallback onArrowTap;
  final HomeProvider homeProvider;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  CustomAppBarWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.animation,
      required this.onArrowTap,
      required this.homeProvider});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  AuthService().getUserUID != null
                      ? IconButton(
                          icon: ImageUtils.imageUtilsInstance
                              .showSVGIcons(menuIcon, height: 30.h),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                          },
                        )
                      : SizedBox(),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      homeProvider.toggleAnimation(context);
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          homeProvider.displayLocation,
                          style: textSemiBold(size: 18, color: colortextBlack),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 8),
                        RotationTransition(
                          turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(
                              homeProvider.animation), // Inverser l'angle
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                            color: colorGrey74797D,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  AuthService().getUserUID != null
                      ? homeProvider.gettingProfile
                          ? SizedBox(
                              height: 20.h,
                              width: 20.h,
                              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  strokeWidth: 1),
                            )
                          : IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                UserSingleton.shared.isPro
                                    ? homeProvider.proProfilePressed()
                                    : homeProvider.customerProfilePressed();
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                color: colortextBlack,
                              ),
                            )
                      : IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            changeScreenReplacement(routeName: signInRoute);
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: colortextBlack,
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(24),
              ),
              child: SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 300.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: commonSymmetricPadding(),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                const Text(
                                  "Ville",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF463F32),
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 14),
                                Container(
                                  height: 56,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 18.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFFE9E9E9),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: TypeAheadField<String>(
                                          noItemsFoundBuilder:
                                              (BuildContext context) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Aucun élément trouvé !"),
                                            );
                                          },
                                          suggestionsBoxDecoration:
                                              SuggestionsBoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                          ),
                                          textFieldConfiguration:
                                              TextFieldConfiguration(
                                            controller:
                                                homeProvider.cityController,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              hintText: "Ville",
                                              filled: true,
                                              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                                              border: InputBorder.none,
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                                  0), // Ajout de cette ligne
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                                            return await homeProvider
                                                .fetchSuggestions(pattern);
                                          },
                                          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                                            return ListTile(
                                              title: Text(
                                                suggestion,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  // Couleur du texte
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      16.0, // Taille du texte
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              tileColor: Colors
                                                  .white, // Couleur d'arrière-plan
                                            );
                                          },
                                          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                                            homeProvider.cityController.text =
                                                suggestion;
                                            homeProvider.currentLocation.city =
                                                suggestion;
                                            homeProvider.notifyListeners();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Icon(Icons.pin_drop_outlined,
                                          color: Color(0xFF050A0A)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "Distance",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF463F32),
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 14),
                                Container(
                                  height: 56,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 18.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFFE9E9E9),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: TextField(
                                          controller: homeProvider.distanceController,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          inputFormatters: [
                                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                                RegExp(r'^\d{0,3}$')),
                                          ],
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            contentPadding:
                                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 18.0,
                                            ),
                                            hintText: "100",
                                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0x80050A0A),
                                            ),
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const Text("km",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xFF050909),
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                ValidateOutlinedButtonWidget(
                                  actionButton: () {
                                    homeProvider.setDistance(homeProvider.distanceController.text);
                                  },
                                  title: "VALIDER",
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm utilizing riverpod with a provider to manage and transmit states across screens. And this widget is inside a screen "homeScreen".

I've also attached an explanatory video here:

[image: preview]

**Edit**

Hello everyone, I've found a solution to my issue, and it might help others who are experiencing similar problems with Textfields losing focus upon tapping:

Indeed, this widget is embedded in a page called "HomeScreen". This page, in fact, had a "UniqueKey" attribute, which was causing a refresh issue, leading to focus problems in the text fields.